# Extracting nouns from WordNet

Tags: c#, wordnet

There are certain nouns that have a plural form. e.g cars.
The rest do not.

I would like to extract from WordNet a list of all nouns except that if the plural form exists, then it's non plural one is excluded.

So, instead of getting car, cars, , only cars,  are extracted.

Is there a command line command to achieve that?

Comment: Does wordnet have an API?

Comment: @Michael Randall Dumps can be downloaded.